# Error `settings.json file has no read or write access` - but permissions OK

Tags: blockchain, synchronization, error

I was downloading the whole Bitcoin blockchain and the download stopped and I got an error message that the settings.json file has no read or write access, but I checked the permissions of the file, and it has read/write access. I saw this question in other places but I couldn't find a solution that works for me. I am using MAC OS X with an external hard drive.

settings.json:

```
{
    
}
```

Edit: There was a problem with running the terminal command so I used the Bitcoin GUI. The download was around halfway done or so.

Comment: Have you tried running bitcoin-qt / bitcoind as root using e.g. `sudo`?